# str_replace with array not working on my bulk upload form

Tags: php

I am using the following code (and it works perfectly) in another upload file of mine to strip and replace punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces found in an image file’s name during the upload process:

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
$file = str_replace(
// punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces to search for in the file's name
array("&","*", " ", "'", "  ", "__", "__", "____", "_____", "*", ":", "@", "!", "$", "(", ")", "?", "[", "]", "<", ">", "`", "=", "{", "}", ";", ",", "/", "~", "#", "%", "^", "+"),
// replacements for punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces found in the file’s name
array("and", "_", "_", "", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "-", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"),
$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

I have tried the same above code in my bulk_upload.php file and it does not work. Punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces found in the image file’s name during the upload process are not stripped and replaced.

I have also tried the above code with the first line of code changed to:

`$filename = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);`

So the code will then become the following:

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
$file = str_replace(
// punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces to search for in the file's name
array("&","*", " ", "'", "  ", "__", "__", "____", "_____", "*", ":", "@", "!", "$", "(", ")", "?", "[", "]", "<", ">", "`", "=", "{", "}", ";", ",", "/", "~", "#", "%", "^", "+"),
// replacements for punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces found in the file’s name
array("and", "_", "_", "", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "-", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"),
$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

But the above code will not work either.

Any help getting the above code to work will be greatly appreciated.

Also, if possible, please could you show me where any code you provide me with should be placed in my bulk_upload.php file.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the full code contained within my bulk_upload.php file:

```
<?php
include '../../config.php';

$securekey = md5($setting['license_key'].$setting['cron_last_run']);

if ($_GET['key'] == $securekey) {

    if ($_FILES["Filedata"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        $directory = "../../files/$_GET[folder]/";

        $filename = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
        $file = str_replace(
        // punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces to search for in the file's name
            array("&","*", " ", "'", "  ", "__", "__", "____", "_____", "*", ":", "@", "!", "$", "(", ")", "?", "[", "]", "<", ">", "`", "=", "{", "}", ";", ",", "/", "~", "#", "%", "^", "+"),
        // replacements for punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces found in the file’s name
            array("and", "_", "_", "", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "-", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"),
            $_FILES['file']['name']);

        $valid_extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'GIF');
        if (!in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($filename)." is not an image file";
        }
        elseif (file_exists($directory . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"])) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]) . " already exists. ";
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], $directory . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
        }
    }

}
else {
    echo 'Invalid security clearance. Please Try Again.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], $directory . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
```

You're supposed to use `$file`, not `$_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]`. I.e.:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], $directory . $file);
```

Comment: Eduardo, Thank you. You solved the problem I was having with an image file's name not being stripped and replaced during the upload process. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the str_replace call you're still using `$_FILES['file']['name']`, where it should be `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']`.

Comment: I changed the str_replace call to `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']`  as you suggested, but the punctuation marks, symbols, and spaces are still not being stripped and replaced in the file's name during the upload process. Any other suggestions?